# Use a Token in Minimum Field

Tags: nodes

I am new to rather new to Drupal (coming from Django/Python), and was wondering if there was anyway I could use a token in the minimum field of my registration.

What I basically have is a registration from, which is then a field in one of my content types. In this content type I also have a field called **minimum deposit**. So I wondering if I could somehow link the value in the minimum deposit field to the minimum in my registration? Like for the minimum value have: `[node:minimum_deposit]`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: are you trying to set the default value of the "minimum deposit" field in your registration form to contain the same value as in the field "minimum deposit" in a pre-existing node?

Comment: Yes, essentially that is that I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, there is no way that I know to do this with a token. You need to create a custom module that implements `hook_form_alter()` to set the default value of your minimum deposit field before the form is rendered. You'll set this default value using the value of the field in the pre-existing node (you'll need to load the node programmatically within the hook function and get the value of the field).

I could give you more details if you let me know what type of form you are using: are you creating a form programmatically with Form API? Using Entityform module to create the form? Using Webform module? Using the "Add to Cart" form provided by the module Drupal Commerce? Post a comment below and I'll edit this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am using the [Entity Response](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module.

Comment: Do you think you can handle it with the information I had above? Do you have other specific questions?

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly new, but I have a good idea of what I should be looking into now. Thanks.